# Rails initializer loaded even when deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been playing around with Formtastic and had some issues with the HTML it using. I found [this monkeypatch](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap/issues/42) which said it could fix the issue, (which it didn't, ha!)

The problem I have now is the `load_lib.rb` file I put in initializers is now being called even though the file has been deleted

```
/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- formtastic_bootstrap_monkeypatch (LoadError)
```

It's saying this because further down it's saying

```
config/initializers/load_lib.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Both the monkeypatch file and load_lib have been deleted.

I do have a couple of other apps running (on unicorn) do I need to stop them too flush what I presuming some caching issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you stopped and started the process (unicorn by the sounds of it) which is running rails?

Comment: I have yes, but there are two other unicorns running for different apps so I'll try them tomorrow